# How to replace NaN values in Pandas conditionally?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using famous Titanic dataset for my first Kaggle problem. I'm getting stuck in dataset.
I want to replace NaN values of Age gender wise e.g. missing values for 'male' should get replaced by average age of Male and vice-versea.
While my code is running fine but getting an exception as following:
"SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)"

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df[(df['Sex']=='male') & (df['Age'].apply(np.isnan))]['Age'].fillna(df[df['Sex']=='male']['Age'].mean(),inplace=True)
```

Comment: It's not an exception, it's just a warning. There's plenty of info if you Google that warning text. In plenty of cases it makes no difference in getting the expected result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Comment: Oops I just checked it thanks, but NaN values in Age are still not getting replaced:

Comment: In any case, the answer you've been given is much more elegant than your existing code, dupe or not :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby(["Sex"])["Age"].transform(np.mean), inplace=True)
```

---

Maybe this was something you were trying to do? I didn't get any warning though. Have a look at [my blog post](http://higee.io/220905703094) too if necessary.

Comment: It's working now, seems need to work on Pandas features.
 Thanks a lot!! :)